# Rofi theme configuration not working. Ubuntu Xenial+i3wm

Tags: 16.04, themes, i3-wm

I just installed Ubuntu Gnome 16 on my laptop and decided to have my working DE as i3wm. Everything is fine except for the configuration on rofi.

I tried, with putting config file in directory `~/.config/rofi/config` with below theme

```
rofi.color-enabled: true
rofi.color-window: #393939, #393939, #268bd2
rofi.color-normal: #393939, #ffffff, #393939, #268bd2, #ffffff
rofi.color-active: #393939, #268bd2, #393939, #268bd2, #205171
rofi.color-urgent: #393939, #f3843d, #393939, #268bd2, #ffc39c
```

The rofi is running fine with i3, but just can't get its theme color changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put all settings into the `.Xresources` file in Your home directory (This is the recommended way of configuring rofi).

From man page:

> CONFIGURATION
>
> There are currently three methods of setting
>   configuration options (evaluated in order below):
>
> - System configuration file (f.e. /etc/rofi.conf).
> - Xresources: A method of storing key values in the Xserver. See here for more information. This is the recommended way of configuring rofi.
> - Command-line options: Arguments passed to rofi.

You can always check man page for more info by issuing command `man rofi`.

After each change You need to re-login.

Comment: this works, but is there a reason why having the configuration on ~/.config/rofi/config not working? Reason is I don't want the configurations of my application stored just anywhere for cleaning purposes and easier to maintain, if possible I want them have under ~/.config/ directory.

Comment: You can always use symlink. Create `.Xresources` file inside `~/.config/ directory` and make a `.Xresources` symlink inside home dir pointing to that file.

Comment: Just a heads up: Since the time of this post, rofi has alternated its preferred way of storing settings. Now it recommends storing the configuration at `XDG_USER_CONFIG_DIR/rofi/config` which usually translates to `~/.config/rofi/config`. You can type `rofi -h` to see which configuration file it is fetching.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on xUbuntu 16.04LTS and resolved it by uninstalling the rofi that was installed with `apt install rofi`. The ubuntu repo has the old version which doesn't have its own settings config.

Next I installed the latest stable release from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rofi after installing all the dependencies that were listed in [the docs](https://github.com/DaveDavenport/rofi/blob/next/INSTALL.md). You can just try to install rofi from the downloaded deb package and the terminal will output what dependencies are missing. On my system that included:

```
sudo apt install build-essential libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxcb-ewmh2 libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-xrm0 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xkb1
```

Note that some of the dependencies will need to be downloaded from source like [libxcb-xrm0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/amd64/libxcb-xrm0/download)

```
sudo dpkg -i Downloads/libxcb-xrm0_1.0-2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i Downloads/rofi_1.3.1-2_amd64.deb
```

After the installation was complete, rofi started using my `~/.config/rofi/config` and I did not have to logout and back in

Comment: I used https://launchpad.net/~jasonpleau/+archive/ubuntu/rofi on 16.04LTS and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, I have a similar environment, and prefer to use a separate config file for Rofi in `.config/rofi/config`, and has been like that for more than a year.

Not entirely sure, but I don't think the `color-enabled` is necessary, and might be the reason. But at least the separate config file is not.